# How ground water is brought to surface if maximum suction head is limited to 10 meter?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, civil-engineering

The [depth of groundwater is around 15 to 90 meters][1], while the maximum suction head that can be [created is limited to 10 meters][2] than how this 15 to 90 meters suction head is generated?

[1]: [https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.nationalgeographic.org/encyclopedia/water-tables-and-aquifers/%23:~:text%3DAlthough%2520the%2520water%2520table%2520varies,feet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.nationalgeographic.org/encyclopedia/water-tables-and-aquifers/%23:%7E:text%3DAlthough%2520the%2520water%2520table%2520varies,feet))%2520below%2520the%2520land%2520surface.&ved=2ahUKEwjnmp2A4eP4AhW3R2wGHWuWBEcQFnoECA4QBQ&usg=AOvVaw2aYcIRoTs5PGHslc2XGZPw
[2]: https://www.tec-science.com/mechanics/gases-and-liquids/how-does-a-drinking-straw-work-principle-maximum-suction-lift/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if you put the pump(s) at the bottom of the hole then the suction head is no longer, because you now need the pump(s) to overcome pressure head.

Of course you can use multiple pumps to do 10 meters to fill intermediate reservoirs until you reach the top.

Much like long pipelines that have intermediate pumping stations.